# Is it appropriate to say "l’être" when there is not an exact match between the pronoun "le" and the word it represents?

Tags: pronoms

> Préparez-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez **l’être**.

In conversation with my colleague, I wasn't sure if I could say "vous penserez ***l’être***" in place of "vous penserez ***être préparé***".

If I used the exact same form "préparé" {Participe Passé} in the previous sentence, this would not pose any problem. But strictly speaking, the pronoun "le" here is supposed to be a replacement for the reflexive "***Préparez***-vous" or "se ***préparer***" which is not an exact match.

I wonder if it is acceptable to use the pronoun "le" like this, as long as it concerns the same verb?

Comment: (« *Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez **l’être*** » J'imagine facilement Heidegger déclarant ça à ses étudiants.) Mais pour répondre en résumé à ta question, oui la tournure est maladroite. On comprend cependant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This sentence doesn't work. A native wouldn't say it and would have difficulty understanding it. It's possible to guess what you meant to say, but it isn't straightforward.

You can use “**l'être” to refer to a previous verb clause where the verb is *être* or a few other verbs that express state.

> Je suis prêt à me lancer. Elle l'est aussi.   (*I am ready to get into the action. So is she.*)
>   Ses cheveux deviennent de plus en plus gris. Sa barbe l'est déjà.   (*His hair is becoming more and more gray. His beard is already gray.*)

Note that *le* always refers to the complement of the verb. The verb itself is not part of the referent of the pronoun. The verb has to be repeated, possibly changed to a verb in the same category (as in the second example with *devenir X* and *l'être*).

For an action verb, it's common to use *faire* in the second clause rather than repeat the specific action.

> Préparez-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir si vous avez besoin d'aide pour le faire.   (Prepare yourselves well before starting. Come back to see me if you need help to do it. — In both French and English, in this example, it is ambiguous whether *le/it* refers to *préparez/prepare* or *lancer/starting*.)

In the sentence you're trying to construct, there's no adjective or noun for the pronoun *le* to refer to, so you need to use one. Also, I wouldn't use “*une fois que*” here, because it has a certain definiteness that clashes with “*vous penserez*”.

> Préparez-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir quand vous penserez être prêts.
>   Préparez-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir une fois que vous serez prêts.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec votre exemple de la barbe. 
Je n'utiliserais pas le pronom pour un adjectif qui devrait changer de genre, surtout si ça s'entend.

Comment: @Distic Ah bon ? Je ne vois vraiment pas pourquoi. Et s'il change de nombre ?

Comment: J'espère que mon précédent commentaire ne vous a pas paru trop dur. Je ne suis pas linguiste professionnel, donc je ne peux pas vous garantir que ça ne se dit pas. Simplement, quand je vous ai lu, je me suis tout de suite demandé : elle est "gris", sa barbe ? Je pense que c'est un problème d'oreille plutôt que de grammaire proprement dite. Si vous aviez une source attestant cet usage, je serais content d'apprendre quelque chose.

Comment: @Distic https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26763/pronom-relatif-dont-lant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent-est-un-adjectif-de-genre-diff%C3%A9rent

Answer (score 1):

Je vais construire ma réponse à partir de la réflexion de la question qui interpelle sur le rôle des pronoms (personnels). Le sujet mériterait certainement d'être poursuivi sur [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) car ce rôle peut varier selon les langues et toutes les langues n'emploieraient pas un pronom personnel dans cette phrase donnée dans la question<sup>2</sup> :

*But strictly speaking, the pronoun "le" here is supposed to be a replacement for the reflexive "Préparez-vous" or "se préparer" which is not an **exact match***. (c'est moi qui souligne).

Définition du **pronom** dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse,10<sup>e</sup> édition) :

> Le « pronom » est un mot qui souvent représente un nom, un adjectif, une idée ou une proposition exprimé avant ou après lui.

Il existe de nombreuses définitions de « pronom personnel » la plupart revenant à dire ce qu'on trouve sur [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_personnel) :

> En grammaire, le pronom personnel est une catégorie de pronoms servant à désigner les trois types de personnes grammaticales.

Je ne me risquerai pas moi-même à une définition du pronom personnel.<sup>2</sup>  Ce que je retiens c'est que le pronom peut se substituer à un syntagme nominal, une idée, un adjectif, etc... qu'ils soient exprimés ou qu'ils découlent du contexte.

Quelques exemples utilisés dans l'apprentissage du FLE.

> Le pronom est un mot qui remplace :
>   Un nom :  *Où est mon livre? – Il est sur la table*.
>   Un adjectif:  *Gourmands, ils le sont, mais pas à ce point*.
>   Une proposition :  *Autrefois, j’étais amoureux d’elle. Je ne le suis plus*.  ([Espace Francais](http://www.espacefrancais.com/les-pronoms/#Dfinition))

> Le pronom peut cependant aussi se substituer à d’au­tres par­ties du discours que le GN :
>   Adjectif : Toi tu es **content**, moi je **le** suis moins.
>   Verbe:  N’oublie pas de **téléphoner** → Je **le** ferai.
>   Proposition: Les élèves ne sont pas habitués **à ce qu’on leur fasse des critiques**. → Ils n’**y** sont pas habitués.
>   Le pronom peut éga­le­ment renvoyer à une idée non exprimée mais déductible du contexte.
>   ([La grammaire du français langue étrangère pour étudiants finnophones](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/215.html))

Dans la phrase proposée dans la question :

> Préparez-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez **l**’être.

le pronom **le** (l') remplace l'adjectif / participe passé ***bien préparé*** qui est sous-entendu et découle du contexte de la phrase précédente. (Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez être **bien préparé**.)

Pour moi la phrase est tout à fait correcte et se comprend parfaitement. Mais je ne le dirais pas (opinion personnelle), je préférerais répéter l'adjectif : « Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez être prêt / bien préparé ».

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Dont l'anglais qui dirait "... *when you think you are*".</sub> 
<sup>2</sup>  <sub>Voir l'introduction du livre *Le pronom personnel dans le français parlé* (Calogero Giardina, 2011)</sub>

Comment: Non, ça ne se comprend pas parfaitement. Il faut relire la phrase pour être sûr qu'il n'y a aucune autre possibilité que ce qu'on devine. À l'oral je serais perdu. Et je ne vais même pas chercher dans la littérature, parce que je pense que ce serait vain.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez je ne vois pas ce qui te déroute dans la phrase, pour moi grammaticalement incorrecte mais qui se comprend très bien même si c'est maladroit.

Comment: Je suis d'accord. Le problème ne réside pas dans l'usage du pronom lui-même (techniquement, ce serait un pro-adjectif, Grevisse parle des *formes conjointes attribut du sujet*), mais dans le fait que l'antécédent est sous-entendu. je suis d'accord que la phrase est très compréhensible, même si la grammaire est douteuse (je ne suis pas certain qu'elle soit *formellement* incorrecte, particulièrement si on tient compte de la grammaire orale).

Answer (score 1):

De mon point de vue, les phrases "Préparez-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez l’être." sont peu claires car on ne sait pas ce que reprend le pronom : est-ce l'idée d'être prêt ou le fait de s'y être lancé ? A priori, j'aurais plutôt interprété comme "Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez être lancé." sans en être satisfait.

La formulation "Préparez-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez être prêt." ne me convient pas non plus, car j'ai l'impression de répéter "prêt", ce qui est laid. J'aurais plutôt formulé complètement autrement:
"Avant de vous y lancer, préparez-vous bien et revenez me voir."

Answer (score 1):

This sounds awkward and is arguably grammatically incorrect as explained by Gilles and Laure. A small change would make it right though:

> **Soyez prêt** avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir une fois que vous
>   penserez l’être.

Answer (score -2):

When you ask something about a state (emotional or physical), AND if the state was already announced, you can skip to announce it a second time.

> **Préparez**-vous bien avant de vous y lancer. Revenez me voir une fois que vous penserez **l**’être.

In your sentence, "le" allows you to speak of the readiness of your partner. You can use it in others circumstances.

Example : when asking about if a friend was afraid in a ghost train.

> J'ai eu **peur** dans le train fantômes. Tu **l**'as pas été ?

Comment: La dernière phrase est incorrecte. Ce pourrait être, éventuellement : « Et toi ?»

Comment: J'ai un peu tordu la grammaire pour faire cet exemple, mais sinon je suis d'accord.

Comment: No, the second example would be “Tu ne l'as pas eu”. French speakers would not say “tu ne l'as pas été” and would need to pause to understand it.