# Pronom dont l'antécédent est un attribut de genre différent

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs, accord, pronoms-personnels

Un pronom dont l'antécédent est attribut du sujet peut-il avoir un genre ou un nombre différent de son antécédent ?

Par exemple, les passages suivants sont-ils corrects et idiomatiques ?

> Pierre est malade. Marie l'est aussi.
> Pierre est malade. Paul et Jacques le sont aussi.
>
> Pierre est grand. Marie l'est aussi.
> Pierre est grand. Paul et Jacques le sont aussi.
>
> Pierre est beau. Marie l'est aussi.
> Pierre est beau. Paul et Jacques le sont aussi.

D'après le [*Journal de la langue française et des langues en général*, SLD G.-N. Redler, Tome I, 1838, p. 83](https://books.google.fr/books?id=o_AzAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA83&dq=%22sa+femme+l%27est%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sa%20femme%20l%27est%22&f=false), le cinquième exemple est « une faute d'accord qui ne saurait se justifier ». Cette source critique également une autre phrase :

> Il avait pour ce genre de travail un talent distingué, et une patience qui l'était encore plus.   ([J. J. Barthelemy, *Mémoires*, 1792](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-k0M1kEdBY0C&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%22pour+ce+genre+de+travail+un+talent+distingu%C3%A9+et+une+patience%22&source=bl&ots=e4dhrEh-Y4&sig=gBi8UcV7okBU53dKYmirNl6gaSw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22pour%20ce%20genre%20de%20travail%20un%20talent%20distingu%C3%A9%20et%20une%20patience%22&f=false))

M. Barthelemy ne serait sans doute pas d'accord. Le traducteur de [Florentin Smarandache (*Leitmotive*, 2000)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wW7zAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22sa+femme+l%27est%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sa%20femme%20l%27est%22&f=false) admet le premier exemple, tout comme [Viktoriya et Patrice Lajoye (*Sadko et autres chants mythologiques des Slaves de l'Est (Biélorussie — Russie — Ukraine)*, 2015)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7k3BBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22sa+femme+l%27est%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22sa%20femme%20l%27est%22&f=false). Et [deux participants sur ce site ne sont pas d'accord](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26746/is-it-appropriate-to-say-l-%c3%aatre-when-there-is-not-an-exact-match-between-the-p/26762#comment54458_26762).

Qu'en disent d'autres gens qui ont étudié la grammaire et l'usage ? Est-ce que l'usage a changé au fil du temps ? La prononciation de l'adjectif a-t-elle une importance ?

Comment: Merci pour toutes ces informations en tout cas !

Comment: "Le cinquième exemple est une faute d'accord" - donc mécaniquement, au moins le troisième aussi, non ?

Answer (score 2):

« **Marie est belle, Pierre l'est aussi** » est le type de phrase qui peut laisser dubitatif et que j'éviterais probablement d'écrire.

Ça n'a pas grand chose à voir avec le genre de « ***l'*** » évoqué par le Grevisse et peut-être par Redler, puisque personne ne conteste que ce ***le*** est depuis longtemps un pronom attribut neutre qui ne s'accorde ni en genre, ni en nombre, mais avec l'incohérence de genres entre ***belle*** et ***Pierre***.

Je n'ai pas trouvé de document évoquant ce problème précis mais j'ai déniché cette illustration dans un manuel scolaire [Français quatrième, nouveau programme, par Hélène Maggiori, Sandrine Girard - Hatier](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7CocDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 7, pour qui l'absence d'accord entre l'adjectif et le ce qu'il qualifie n'est pas rédhibitoire, la phrase étant visiblement prononcée par un garçon :

[image: ma sœur est grande, je le suis aussi]

Ce type de construction ne devrait donc pas être écarté.

Answer (score 1):

Ta théorie est correcte: à une époque, ce pronom a été variable. L'ensemble de ces passages sont parfaitement idiomatiques en français moderne. Mais même en 1838, l'usage dont Redler se plaint était fermement établi. Le type était de toute évidence du genre passéiste.

Grevisse, *Le Bon Usage, 14e éd.*, §673 c) H1:

> C'est Vaugelas [1647] qui a nettement établit la règle de *le* attribut neutre. Cependant, elle ne s'est imposée que longtemps après lui, au XVIIe et même au XVIIIe siècle, on faisait encore varier couramment le pronom: [suit une flopée d'exemples]

Comment: *Le* est bien un pronom neutre mais je ne suis pas encore convaincu que ça réponde à la question.

Comment: Je ne suis pas certain de ce que je suis sensé ajouter? Je veux dire, Gilles semble clairement au courant de l'usage de *le* comme pro-adjectif (ce que Grevisse appelle "forme conjointe attribut du sujet"). Ce qui le rend confus est un usage archaïque que promeut Redler, et qui n'est plus courant d'aucune façon depuis au moins 100 ans.

Comment: Les exemples qui suivent dans le Grevisse font référence à *la* utilisé là où aujourd'hui on utilise *le*. Ce n'est pas exactement le sujet de la question, j'aimerais voir un avis sur « Pierre est beau. Marie l'est aussi. ».

Comment: "L'ensemble de ces passages sont parfaitement idiomatiques en français moderne." Il n'y a absolument *rien de remarquable ou d'inhabituel* dans aucune de ces phrases, alors je ne vois pas quoi ajouter. Les exemples en questions sont ce que Redler (celui dont les commentaires ont provoqué la question de Gilles) voudrait voir, mais qui même à cette époque-là n'était plus un usage normal.

Comment: J'ai indiqué dans ma réponse ce qui peut être considéré comme inhabituel dans ces phrases. PS: J'aurais écrit: « L'ensemble de ces passages **est** parfaitement… »